# How to make partial glossy material without roughness?

Tags: materials, reflection

I want to make a background material like the photo below for a logo. I tried many different techniques but, none worked for me. It's like tinted glossy plastic. It is like it is having reflection of outside world but, not that much.. it is more like opacity. Reflections are partial. Not full reflective. glossy material is not working for logo either. Logo is shiny but when I create a glossy shader It reflects HDRI and looks like steel. If I increase roughness then reflectiveness goes off... I am confused what to do...[image]

**EDIT :**  I tried to give metallic look of value 0.4 and roughness 0.08. But, even a small value of roughness blurs out the refelction. So, Roughness isn't the part of material. I tried to give clearcoat effect too. But, it didn't work.

This is viewport render , metallic 0.4, roughness 0.08 , clearcoat 1 but, still not working for me.

[image]

Comment: Use a Principled BSDF. Maybe try values like 0.4 for Metallic and 0.08 for Roughness (Light blue/grey basecolor).

Comment: You might also try messing with the clearcoat setting.

Comment: When using a _Principled BSDF_, try lowering the _Specular_ value from its default 0.5 to much smaller values like 0.2, 0.1 or even 0.05, this should "fade" the reflection without blurring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with different value of roughness , specular and clearcoat I was able to achive the result I wanted. [image]

above displayed result needed very small amount of specular and clearcoat. both set to 0.001 and roughness 0 with principled shader.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant in my comment. The main factor to get the result you want is to lower the specualrity. I was just preparing some example images, but good to see you found a way.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, Thanks alot. Your guidance was the key I figured my way. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, you can accept your own answer as solution so everybody can see that the problem is solved.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I tried, But website is showing me that I can accpet my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Oh,yes of course, I see.